# How to prune content going from Desktop site version to Tablet/Mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a desktop site version that looks like this:
[Desktop Version Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/555ey.jpg)

I made mobile version with @mediaquery who looks like this:
[Mobile Version Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYhz.jpg)

In the Business Academy we have been taught to prune and minimize content on Mobile versions, but funny enough they didn't told how to edit content.

My question is how I can change for example the big fat header in desktop version that says "We are looking for volunteers to help us...bla..bla..bla" to Mobile version who contains only 2 words - "Volunteering Opportunities" ?

I would be super grateful for any responses, cheers!

Comment: What is the html code that shows that text? There are several approaches you could take to change it.

Comment: @Yura  Thanks for the response! I forgot to mention, that the main text is displayed by PHP Include function, which includes separate posts as plain text with <h2> and <p> tags, nothing more. But I think this would get too complicated with PHP for me. Lets just assume that I have simple <h2> heading with lots of characters in it on desktop version   and I would like to display header on mobile version just like this <h2> Volunteering Opportunities </h2>. Hope you get it what I mean :)

Comment: You will need to create two elements for the two versions of the text. You might create those two elements inside your `<h2>` element. Then assign them classes and use the css that I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Yura  Thank you for your help, I will dig into it straight away!

Comment: In fact I have just updated my answer with the `<h2>` to match your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text by creating two elements with both versions of the text, and then show and hide them with media queries depending on screen size.

If you are using Bootstrap, you can use the [responsive utilites](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for that. If not, you can include your custom css which does the same.

I have included a working example below. Run it full page and resize the screen to see it in work.

```css
.visible-xs-inline {
  display: none;
}

/** Styles for small screen */
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .visible-xs-inline {
      display: inline!important;
  }
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span class="hidden-xs">
    We are looking for volunteers to help us during our European Green Election campain!
  </span>  
  <span class="visible-xs-inline">
    Volunteering Opportunities
  </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: I'd not recommend this kind of practice; this will lead to load into mobile browsers (and desktop too) a lot of unwanted end useless stuffs. What's going to happen when we want two different version of images?... the browser will load two for each!
If the goal is just minimizing the text itself, semantically and linguistically speaking, the CSS are nothing related to that. Whould be better think to implement specific algoritms; some of them not too difficoult to manage, and free...

Comment: Holden, the question is not about images, it's about showing two versions of text. You might do it with javascript, but that might be an overhead. Using media queries is lightweight, also included into bootstrap, which makes it somewhat one of most straightforward and simple to manage solutions.

Comment: If your problem is with the question, please comment on the question, or add your answer otherwise.

Comment: @holden Hi, it was just for very basic change in the website. Nothing too complicated. But I got your idea. And I'm curious about what algorithms you are talking? You mean a script of PHP or JavaScript  who can detect the mobile device and then load different content or something else? Share your insights :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to get the results you want.

You can either look at having both mobile and desktop versions of the content in the html but use media queries in the CSS to hide and show the correct content for the device.

Or you could look at using something like this - http://stephanfowler.com/responsive-content/  This is a jquery plugin called responsive-content.

I'd also recommend having a read of this article - http://summit.stc.org/responsive/summit2014.htm#!Documents/informationeverywhereflexiblecontentwithresponsivedesign.htm

> RESPONSIVE IS ABOUT CONTEXT
>
> Responsive design is part of a web development philosophy called Progressive Enhancement. Web designers who have embraced Progressive Enhancement believe that users should not miss out on a great experience – or content – because they don’t have the “right” device or browser. As Aaron Gustafson noted in Adaptive Web Design: Crafting Rich Experiences with Progressive Enhancement: “Progressive enhancement is a philosophy aimed at crafting experiences that serve your users by giving them access to content without technological restrictions.”
>
> Responsive design is all about accommodating the user’s context — their environment, device, and more. Technical communicators have always considered context when doing project planning. It is one component of our mantra “know your audience.”

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!